# Why would the same object initialized the same way have different values?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, memorystream

I have to different programs that are using a `System.IO.MemoryStream`.  I create it like so in both, `MemoryStream fpms = new MemoryStream();`

In program 1 `fpms` has `Length` and `Position` set to `0`.  This program works as expected.

In program two, same line of code but those 2 properties are set to `-1092826431` and `-757670183` respectively.  This program generates an `IOException` as soon as it hits my first `fpms.Write()` call.

I've tried manually setting the `Position` and `Length` to `0` but that also generates an exception on the `fpms.SetLength())` call.  Any thoughts as to why these two objects start life with different values?

These are both .Net Compact Framework 3.5 apps on WinCE 6.

Comment: So you are attempting to set the position and length of a MemoryStream which hasn't had anything written into it? It might be worth actually posting complete code to see what you're doing with the MemoryStream.

Comment: @CathalMF He says he "tried", just as a test, to set those, seeing that he was observing the described behavior.

Comment: No and yes, I was simply trying to 'Band-Aid' my problem.  My issue is that in Program 2 a `new MemoryStream()` starts out with Position and Length values of the above stated.

Comment: Also, I should note, that if I fire up a console app and instantiate a `new MemoryStream()` I get 0 for the starting values there as well....

Comment: What happens if you try to explicitly pass 0 to the constructor ?

Comment: The same.  I think that might be due to the fact that the Constructor with a single Int passed to it is setting the Capacity, not Length or Position.  Maybe...At this point I really have nothing.  I just don't understand how it can be different in 2 different programs when they reference the exact same System.dll.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Can you share a stripped down version of the application that still has the problem? Do you have a second device you can test this on? Or can you reinstall .NET CF on the current?

Comment: It sounds like the 2nd program may be low on memory or out of memory